# typedef struct A A in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Does this mean anything:

```
typedef struct spBone spBone;
struct spBone {
...
}
```

I found the above in a header of a .c file. What could be the side-purpose of assigning a **non-alternative** name to a struct?

Comment: if it is in a .c then its probably C not C++

Comment: It's pointless - delete it.

Comment: Why do you bring up the code of *some other language* for this question about C++?

Comment: Um... It means exactly what it means. It is a useful and widely used idiom in C. It is not clear what you mean by "non-alternative" though. All it does is assign shorter name `spBone` for type `struct spBone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember that C and C++ are different languages. C++ is rooted in C, but went in some very different directions. This is one of them.

When declaring or defining a variable of type `struct` in C, one must always use the keyword `struct`. For example

```
struct spBone myspBone;
```

is required. Why this is required likely made a lot of sense back in the 1970s.

However, the programmer is establishing `spBone` as an alias to `struct spBone` so that they can use the alias and

```
spBone myspBone;
```

as you can in C++.

Comment: Gosh, I didn't notice the *struct* keyword *after* typedef, even though I copy-pasted it.